# Could you help me understand the sequence of execution?

Tags: javascript

```
doA(function(){
  doB();
  doC(function() {
    doD();
  })
  doE();
});
doF();
```

#### excution order

doA() -> doF() -> doB() -> doC() -> doE() -> doD()

I don't understand why the execution order is as above...:(

Comment: what order did you expect? how do doA and doC call their supplied callbacks?

Comment: @Bravo I don't know the exact order. But I don't understand that doF is executed after doA.

Comment: It's because, doA() is is taking the other function as a argument. So, it makes doA() just a normal function call. And because of the sequence of function calls, doF() called after doA().

Comment: it really depends on what doA does - i.e. do doA and doC call the callback synchronously or asynchronously - also, depends on how you determine when a function is executing

Answer (score 0):

The order the functions are executed depends on how doA and doC call their respective callbacks

Synchronously

```js
function doA(cb) { console.log('doA'); cb(); }
function doB() { console.log('doB'); }
function doC(cb) { console.log('doC'); cb(); }
function doD() { console.log('doD'); }
function doE() { console.log('doE'); }
function doF(cb) { console.log('doF');}

doA(function(){
  doB();
  doC(function() {
    doD();
  })
  doE();
});
doF();
```

or Asynchronously

```js
function doA(cb) { console.log('doA'); setTimeout(cb); }
function doB() { console.log('doB'); }
function doC(cb) { console.log('doC'); setTimeout(cb); }
function doD() { console.log('doD'); }
function doE() { console.log('doE'); }
function doF(cb) { console.log('doF');}

doA(function(){
  doB();
  doC(function() {
    doD();
  })
  doE();
});
doF();
```